# How can i check if number is matching a specific criteria with regexp in php

Tags: php, regex

I need to validate a phone number and make sure it is starting with a specific 4 digits (2010,2011,2012) plus more 7 digits by using regular expressions in php.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? I would recommend using https://regex101.com/ to quickly see how things work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job

```
^201(0|1|2){1}(\d){7}$
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :)